# Retornar a categoria a diferença do RGB seja menor

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, rgb

eu estou com uma dúvida, que provavelmente eu esteja tentando "reinventar a roda", mas não consegui chegar num resultado.

Eu tenho uma matriz de cores (em RGB):

```
{
    "muito-clara": [248,299,218],
    "clara": [243,209,180],
    "clara-media": [221,175,134],
    "escura-media": [203,126,85],
    "escura": [154,73,33],
    "muito-escuro": [73,30,12]
}
```

E preciso comparar elas com outra RGB que eu recebo. Ex: RGB[234, 222, 213]

Eu preciso "retornar" a cor que tem maior aproximação.

Cheguei ao código abaixo:

```
json_data = json.loads(matriz_uau)

cor = []
aux1 = 0

for i in json_data:
  for k in json_data[i]:
    cor.append(k)
  color1_rgb = sRGBColor(int(rgb1), int(rgb2), int(rgb3))
  color2_rgb = sRGBColor(int(cor[0]), int(cor[1]), int(cor[2]))
  color1_lab = convert_color(color1_rgb, LabColor);
  color2_lab = convert_color(color2_rgb, LabColor);
  delta_e = delta_e_cie2000(color1_lab, color2_lab);
  if (aux1 < delta_e):
    aux1 = delta_e
  cor = []

print(aux1)
```

Porém o resultado é sempre um número, porém não consigo relacionar ele com a categoria.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes tentar fazendo a soma da diferença absoluta entre cada cor da lista e a cor que queres verificar qual o que tem menor diferença da cor de referência:

```
from math import sqrt

def closest_color(color, colors):
        r, g, b = color
        color_diffs = []
        for cr, cg, cb in colors:
                color_diff = sqrt(abs(r - cr)**2 + abs(g - cg)**2 + abs(b - cb)**2)
                color_diffs.append((color_diff, (cr, cg, cb)))
        return min(color_diffs)[1]

colors = {
    "muito-clara": [248,299,218],
    "clara": [243,209,180],
    "clara-media": [221,175,134],
    "escura-media": [203,126,85],
    "escura": [154,73,33],
    "muito-escuro": [73,30,12]
}

print(closest_color((234, 222, 213), colors.values())) # (243, 209, 180)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/IllfatedAwesomeIntegrationtesting)